# Unity3D - Light deactivated when facing opposite direction

Tags: unity-game-engine, lighting

I placed a light in my scene.

It is lighting the ground when i'm facing that light but when I turn the opposite direction, the light on the ground vanishes.

I think this might be some Unity's default behaviour.

Is there a way I can solve this issue?

Comment: what kind of a light is it? Directional? Spot? Point?

Comment: It is a point light used through à particle system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity uses frustum culling to save performance, so it only draws items that are within the camera's viewing area. As a result of this, the particles *behind* you are not drawn, and any lights attached to them aren't either.

Scene-crucial lights aren't normally attached to particles, so it's normally not a concern if they're hidden along with their particles.

For conventional lights (not attached to particles), Unity should render the light as long as it affects objects within the camera frustum. If you use a conventional light, you should see better results.

Comment: Indeed! Maximilian's link made me notice that the problem came from the Frustum culling and not the Occlusion culling. I just need to find a way to make my light feel like it's a burning fire (like she did when she was attached to the particle sytem) Guess I'll have to do that with a script :P

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you may have to disable occlusion culling. [Unity3D Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OcclusionCulling.html)